# Iterating over overridden Values in a Scala Enumeration

Tags: java, scala, enums, iteration

I'm currently trying to replicate the Java enumeration shown [here](http://pastebin.com/HVpdiPsp) in Scala. Here's what I have so far:

```
object DataType extends Enum {
  val BYTE = CCSValue(classOf[Byte], classOf[java.lang.Byte], "byte")
  val SHORT = CCSValue(classOf[Short], classOf[java.lang.Short], "short")
  val INTEGER = CCSValue(classOf[Int], classOf[Integer], "int")
  val LONG = CCSValue(classOf[Long], classOf[java.lang.Long], "long")
  val CHARACTER = CCSValue(classOf[Char], classOf[Character], "char")
  val FLOAT = CCSValue(classOf[Float], classOf[java.lang.Float], "float")
  val DOUBLE = CCSValue(classOf[Double], classOf[java.lang.Double], "double")
  val BOOLEAN = CCSValue(classOf[Boolean], classOf[java.lang.Boolean], "boolean")

  class PRDataType(val primitive: Class[_], val reference: Class[_], name: String) extends Val(nextId, name)
  protected final def CCSValue(primitive: Class[_], reference: Class[_], name: String): PRDataType = new PRDataType(primitive, reference, name)

  private val CLASS_MAP = new mutable.HashMap[Class[_], PRDataType]()

  for (item: PRDataType <- values.toArray) {
    CLASS_MAP.put(item.primitive, item)
    CLASS_MAP.put(item.reference, item)
  }
}
```

However, when I execute this in the Scala REPL, I get the following error:

```
location\of\script\test.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
found   : Main.$anon.DataType.PRDataType => Option[Main.$anon.DataType.PRDataType]
required: Main.$anon.DataType.Value => ?
   for (item: PRDataType <- values.toArray) {
                         ^
```

Am I doing something really silly? I'm new to Scala, and this is the best way I could find to define enumeration constants that weren't just an id and a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make it compile

> values.toArray.map(_.asInstanceOf[PRDataType])